# ios ble - Write Without Response" property - ignoring response-less write

Tags: ios, bluetooth-lowenergy, core-bluetooth

On iOS7.1.1, the following BLE operation succeeds - it assumes I have a BLE connection setup etc...

```
[[self peripheral]writeValue:dataToWrite forCharacteristic:nextCharacteristic type:CBCharacteristicWriteWithResponse];
```

But If I switch the "type" to `CBCharacteristicWriteWithoutResponse`, I get the following warning and the peripheral does not receive the command :(

```
[[self peripheral]writeValue:dataToWrite forCharacteristic:nextCharacteristic type:CBCharacteristicWriteWithoutResponse];
```

Error:

```
CoreBluetooth[WARNING] Characteristic <CBCharacteristic: 0x178081f90 UUID = 249C2001-00D7-4D91-AC75-22D57AE2FFB8, Value = (null), Properties = 0x28, Notifying = YES, Broadcasting = NO> does not specify the "Write Without Response" property - ignoring response-less write**
```

Any clues appreciated!

Answer (score 17, accepted):

When a BLE peripheral advertises characteristics the advertisement includes the properties of those characteristics. These include what operations are supported on that characteristic - read, notify, write without response and write with response.

In this case it seems that the characteristic supports write with response but not write without response, so when you attempt a write without response you get the warning and the write operations doesn't complete

Comment: Perfect on the spot answer - on ios this check is performed but on some oter platforms, the BLE implementation does not do this check and so it worked fine with the correct flags in the charcteristics.

Comment: forgot to mention that a firmware change was required to fix the problem... Thx Paul:)

Comment: @Paul: DId u succeed to update firmware version?  CoreBluetooth[WARNING] Characteristic <CBCharacteristic: 0x178081f90 UUID = 249C2001-00D7-4D91-AC75-22D57AE2FFB8, Value = (null), Properties = 0x28, Notifying = YES, Broadcasting = NO> does not specify the "Write Without Response" property - ignoring response-less write** I am getting warning

Comment: @DevangBhavsar; Hi, it wasn't my firmware, it was the OP's; I assume that they did since they resolved the problem.  In your case it seems that you are issuing a write without response, but the characteristic only supports write with response (properties = 0x28) See https://github.com/theos/sdks/blob/master/iPhoneOS9.3.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreBluetooth.framework/Headers/CBCharacteristic.h

Comment: bro how do i set write with value? how can i define it?

Comment: The properties of the characteristic are set by the device you are connecting to.  In this case, unless you change the device, you need to specify `.withResponse` as the `type` when you call `writeValue` for the characteristic.  If you still aren't clear, then I suggest you ask your own question.

Comment: sure bro thanks for informing that let me do this thanks bro

Comment: but bro i am not assigning any value in that as when there is a method which is getting called like  func bleManagerPeripheral(_ peripheral: CBPeripheral!, didUpdateValueFor characteristic: CBCharacteristic!, error: Error!) {
  /// iam using this charstics
}

can u please suggest how to set permissions and all

Comment: Please ask a new question, showing the relevant code and explaining what is happening and what you want to happen.

Comment: plz check my question